# How to add JSON string into VueX store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working with a JSON output which an example is:

```
{"driver_id":1,"driver_name":"{driver_first_name}, {driver_last_name}","driver_truck":"13","driver_trailer":"83","driver_status":"driving","has_violations":false},
{"driver_id":2,"driver_name":"{driver_first_name}, {driver_last_name}","driver_truck":"58","driver_trailer":"37","driver_status":"sleeping","has_violations":true},
{"driver_id":3,"driver_name":"{driver_first_name}, {driver_last_name}","driver_truck":"80","driver_trailer":"27","driver_status":"driving","has_violations":true},
```

This JSON data is then printed by my ***Driver Status*** template in a table with a button called ***"View Violations"*** conditionally rendered when has_violations equals true. The only part of that JSON data that isn't printed is `driver_id`.

What I am trying to accomplish is when a user presses the **View Violations** button they are taken to another template called ***Driver Violations*** which will then take the `driver_id` given to it from ***Driver Status*** and send a JSON request to get the list of all violations from the backend.

I am trying to have `driver_id` passed over depending on the button that is clicked on but I am going somewhere wrong, this my attempt:

This is specifically my attempt:

```
  <!-- VueX Store driver_id -->
  <template slot="actions" slot-scope="row">
    <b-button @click="getAllViolations(driver_id)" v-if="row.value.list_of_violations == true" id="account_list">View Violations</b-button>
  </template>

<template>
  <b-container fluid>

    <!--Search Controls-->
    <b-row>
      <b-col md="6" class="my-1">
        <b-form-group horizontal label="Filter" class="mb-0">
          <b-input-group>
            <b-form-input v-model="filter" placeholder="Type to Search" />
            <b-input-group-append>
              <b-btn :disabled="!filter" @click="filter = ''">Clear</b-btn>
            </b-input-group-append>
          </b-input-group>
        </b-form-group>
      </b-col>
      <b-col md="6" class="my-1">
        <b-form-group horizontal label="Sort" class="mb-0">
          <b-input-group>
            <b-form-select v-model="sortBy" :options="sortOptions">
              <option slot="first" :value="null">-- none --</option>
            </b-form-select>
            <b-form-select :disabled="!sortBy" v-model="sortDesc" slot="append">
              <option :value="false">Asc</option>
              <option :value="true">Desc</option>
            </b-form-select>
          </b-input-group>
        </b-form-group>
      </b-col>
      <b-col md="6" class="my-1">
        <b-form-group horizontal label="Sort direction" class="mb-0">
          <b-input-group>
            <b-form-select v-model="sortDirection" slot="append">
              <option value="asc">Asc</option>
              <option value="desc">Desc</option>
              <option value="last">Last</option>
            </b-form-select>
          </b-input-group>
        </b-form-group>
      </b-col>
      <b-col md="6" class="my-1">
        <b-form-group horizontal label="Per page" class="mb-0">
          <b-form-select :options="pageOptions" v-model="perPage" />
        </b-form-group>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
    <!--Search Controls-->

    <!-- Main table element -->
    <b-table show-empty
             stacked="md"
             :items="items"
             :fields="fields"
             :current-page="currentPage"
             :per-page="perPage"
             :filter="filter"
             :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
             :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
             :sort-direction="sortDirection"
             @filtered="onFiltered"
    >
      <template slot="driverName" slot-scope="row">{{row.value.driver_first_name}} {{row.value.driver_last_name}}</template>
      <template slot="truckNumber" slot-scope="row">{{row.value.driver_truck}}</template>
      <template slot="truckNumber" slot-scope="row">{{row.value.driver_trailer}}</template>
      <template slot="status" slot-scope="row">{{row.value.driver_status}}</template>
      <template slot="violations" slot-scope="row">{{row.value?'Yes':'No'}}</template>
      <!-- VueX Store driver_id -->
      <template slot="actions" slot-scope="row">
        <b-button @click="getAllViolations(driver_id)" v-if="row.value.list_of_violations == true" id="account_list">View Violations</b-button>
      </template>

    </b-table>

    <b-row>
      <b-col md="6" class="my-1">
        <b-pagination :total-rows="totalRows" :per-page="perPage" v-model="currentPage" class="my-0" />
      </b-col>
    </b-row>

  </b-container>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      items: items,
      fields: [
        { key: 'driver_name', label: 'Driver Name', sortable: true, sortDirection: 'desc' },
        { key: 'truck_number', label: 'Truck Number', sortable: true, 'class': 'text-center' },
        { key: 'trailer_number', label: 'Trailer Number', sortable: true, 'class': 'text-center' },
        { key: 'has_violations', label: 'Violations' },
        { key: 'driver_status', label: 'Status' },
        { key: 'actions', label: 'Actions' }
      ],
      currentPage: 1,
      perPage: 5,
      totalRows: items.length,
      pageOptions: [ 5, 10, 15 ],
      sortBy: null,
      sortDesc: false,
      sortDirection: 'asc',
      filter: null,
    }
  },
  },
  computed: {
    sortOptions () {
      return this.fields
        .filter(f => f.sortable)
        .map(f => { return { text: f.label, value: f.key } })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onFiltered (filteredItems) {
      // Trigger pagination to update the number of buttons/pages due to filtering
      this.totalRows = filteredItems.length
      this.currentPage = 1
    }
    //Get JSON
    getDriverStatus: function () {
      const url = 'driver_status_data.json'
        axios.get(url, {
          dataType: 'json',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          mode: 'no-cors',
          credentials: 'include'
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
          this.courses = JSON.stringify(response.data)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error)
        })
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Is my attempt correct here?